# Pip not recognizing PyTorch with ROCm installation

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

On the [PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) it lists two blocks of commands for the ROCm version installation. The first one, that installs torch itself, goes well, but when I try to import it shows this message.

`ImportError: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Also, when trying to install the torchvision package with the second block of commands, it shows a similar error.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`

This only happens for with the ROCm compute platform. Installing with CUDA works just fine, but unfortunately I  don't have a NVidia GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it was a bug that haven't been fixed. You can make a local symbolic link named **libtinfo.6.so** to **/usr/lib/libtinfo5.so**, in the same folder as **libtaichi_core.so**

This should solve it,